# The number of ways of selecting 10 objects from 30 objects, of which 10 are alike and the rest are all different is?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Question based on Permutations and Combinations

The number of ways of selecting 10 objects from 30 objects, of which 10 are alike and the rest are all different is ?

A) $2^{20} + \binom{20}{10}$

B) $2^{20} - \binom{20}{9}$

C) $2^{19} + \binom{20}{9}$

D) $2^{19} - \binom{20}{10}$

Comment: Then you essentially only have $21$ objects to choose from, in which case the answer would be $C^{21}_{10}$

Comment: Nope cause you can choose like 5 of the alike things and then 5 distinct things and such combinations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose $n$ of the unique object, then there are $20\choose n$ ways to pick those, and $1$ to pick the other $10-n$ non-unique ones. So the answer is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10} {20\choose n}$$

By symmetry, we have
$$2\sum_{n=0}^{10} {20\choose n} = \sum_{n=0}^{20} {20\choose n} + {20\choose 10} = 2^{20} + {20\choose 10}$$

So
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10} {20\choose n} = 2^{19} + \frac12{20\choose 10}$$

And ${19\choose10} = {19\choose9}$ and ${19\choose10} + {19\choose9} = {20\choose10}$ by Pascal's Identity, so this gives $\frac12 {20\choose10} = {19\choose9}$ so the final answer is
$$2^{19} + {19\choose 9}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you pick $p$ objects from the set $P$ of identical objects, and let the set $Q$ be that of the other $20$ objects. Scaling $p$ in the range $[0, 10]$ and permuting the ways to complete the $10$ with $Q$ gives us:

$$\sum_{p=0}^{10}\binom{20}{10-p}$$